# Working with @Qualifier in Kotlin functions

Tags: spring, spring-data, kotlin

In Kotlin function parameters are always values which prevents `@Qualifier()` from being used at the parameter level.

If someone wanted to create multiple `DataSource`s in a config class for different databases frequently accessed within the same application what is the recommended way to organize this?

Doing the following which seemed fairly common in Java isn't allowed in Kotlin.

```
@Configuration
class DatabaseAdminConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_admin")
    fun adminDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun adminJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("adminDataSource") dsAdminDb: DataSource): JdbcTemplate {
        return JdbcTemplate(dsAdminDb)
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_widget")
    fun widgetDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun widgetJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("widgetDataSource") widgetDataSource: DataSource): JdbcTemplate {
        return JdbcTemplate(widgetDataSource)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to inject the dependency from the same class into the method that requires that dependency in Spring. You can just call the method directly.

```
@Configuration
class DatabaseAdminConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_admin")
    fun adminDataSource() = DataSourceBuilder.create().build()

    @Bean
    fun adminJdbcTemplate() = JdbcTemplate(adminDataSource())

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_widget")
    fun widgetDataSource() = DataSourceBuilder.create().build()

    @Bean
    fun widgetJdbcTemplate() = JdbcTemplate(widgetDataSource())
}
```

PS: function expression bodies (as above) make Spring Configuration classes look even more concise.

PPS: `@Qualifier` works totally fine for me. I just tested it.

PPPS: And for completeness to address the specific problem, as I commented: You must have accidentally imported the `javax.inject.Qualifier` annotation, which will not work. You need to import the `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` which works

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah the example here is just the easiest non-specific contrived example I could come up with to show the issue I was running into. The Error I receive trying to use @Qualifier in a parameter is "This annotation is not applicable to target 'value parameter'".

Comment: You must have accidentally imported the `javax.inject.Qualifier` annotation, which will not work. You need to import the `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` annotation.